# jQuery Chosen Dropdown validation client site doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, jquery-chosen, html.dropdownlistfor, client-side-validation

My model class contains of required lookup value which is a lookup-based record:

```
[Required]
[DisplayName("Business Unit")]
public string value { get; set; }

[Required] //not working on client side?
[DisplayName("Business Group")]
public int id_businessgroup { get; set; }
```

View:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.value)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.value)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.value)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(x=>x.BusinessGroup.value)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.id_businessgroup, new SelectList(ViewBag.BusinessGroups,"id","value"),"Please select group from list...")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.id_businessgroup)
    </div>

@section scripts{
  @Html.Partial("ScriptUseChosen")
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.BusinessGroups = DB.BusinessGroups.Where(x => x.is_active).OrderBy(x => x.value).ToList();
        return View();
    }
```

Web.config:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

BundleConfig.cs:

```
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*"));
```

Validation for `value` is working perfectly on client side, but it's not working on the Chosen's dropdown. What could be the reason?

Comment: What is the default value that is set in the dropdown whether the option label or any of the value from dropdown on page load?

Comment: As you can see in the View it's text `"Please select group from list..."`

Comment: On post back what data you get for the id_businessgroup property null or "Please select group from list..."?

Comment: Neither, it's set to 0. Keep in mind that I need client side (javascript) validation to work *before* sending anything to server.

Comment: Try setting the property to nullable int `public int? id_businessgroup { get; set; }`

Comment: Then it would be the exact opposite of what I want, I think. This field needs to be required, so shouldn't be null.

Comment: `int` has a default value of `0` which passes `Required` validation (it has a value). `int?` on the other hand has a default value of null, so it you don't select a value, then it will be null so validation will fail and you will get an error when you try to submit.

Comment: I've just tried that, but it's not working also

Comment: You said _"the Chosen's dropdown"_ Are you using a jquery plugin? If so what is the html generated?

Comment: Yes, label text is rendered as `<option value="">Please select group from list...</option>` and I think this might be the issue

Comment: Make sure jquery validator script is loaded inside the browser by viewing age source. I didn't see `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")` in your code!

Comment: They are, since validation for `value` field is working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

jQuery Chosen updates the html by making the original select hidden (`style="Display:none"`). By default jquery.validate (1.9.0) ignores hidden elements. You can override the default using

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ 
  ignore: []
});
```

or

```
$('form').validate({
    ignore: []
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the option label is not rendered as Please select group from list... in your dropdown, then it will be regarded as a selected value by default and the client side validation will pass.

Instead of using ViewBag for databinding try changing your model like below and i tested it's working fine,

```
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Business Unit")]
    public string value { get; set; }

    [Required] //not working on client side?
    [DisplayName("Business Group")]
    public int id_businessgroup { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> BussinessGroup { get; set; }
```

And bind the data to the BussinessGroup in controller like,

```
            BussinessGroup = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = "A",
                    Value = "1"
                },

                    new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = "B",
                    Value = "2"
                }
            }
```

Finally in the view bind the dropdown as,

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.id_businessgroup, Model.BussinessGroup, "Please select group from list...")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.id_businessgroup)
```

Comment: Then, the selected value will be first value from the dropdown (preselected) and I don't want that

Comment: Does your rendered dropdown looks like the below, 
<option value="">Please select group from list...</option>

Comment: Yes, that's the way how it looks like

Comment: @Adrian Did u try in the way using Model property instead ViewBag which i updated in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a quick workaround for that by using jquery's Select2 plugin. I'm leaving this question opened for solution using Chosen.

Comment: Yes, chosen will be opt for this one but if some one not using the chosen they can try using the Enumerable select list item property for dropdown lookup value instead of using the ViewBag. If you could and let others know whether this solution works or not. As it works fine for me. Thanks.