# MVC data validation for listboxfor not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

I am having a bit of trouble with my form being validated even if my listboxfor is empty. This is the viewmodel im using:

```
 public class CopyExcelReportSearchViewModel: IViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public DateRange DateRange { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public List<Guid> ProjectIds { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public List<Guid> LocationsIds { get; set; }
    public List<Customer> AvailableCustomers { get; set; }
    public List<Project> AvailableProjects { get; set; }
    public List<Location> AvailableLocations { get; set; }

    public CopyExcelReportSearchViewModel()
    {
        ProjectIds = new List<Guid>();
        LocationsIds = new List<Guid>();
        AvailableCustomers = new List<Customer>();
        AvailableProjects = new List<Project>();
        AvailableLocations = new List<Location>();
    }
}
```

Here is the html

```
@model    Path.CopyExcelReportSearchViewModel
@{
var customerDropdown = Model.AvailableCustomers.Select(x => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = x.Name,
    Value = x.Id.ToString(),
    Selected = Model.CustomerId == x.Id
});
var locationDropdown = Model.AvailableLocations.Select(x => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = x.Name,
    Value = x.Id.ToString(),
    Selected = Model.LocationsIds.Any(y => y == x.Id)
});
var projectDropdown = Model.AvailableProjects.Select(x => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = x.Name,
    Value = x.Id.ToString(),
    Selected = Model.ProjectIds.Any(y => y == x.Id)
});
}

<script>
    var optionTemplate = [
       '<option value="[VALUE]">[TEXT]</option>'
    ].join();

    $(function () {
        $('#CustomerId').change(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetProjectsByCustomerId")?customerId=' + value,
                datatype: 'json',
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    var projectSelect = $('#ProjectIds');
                    var options = '';
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        options += optionTemplate.replace('[VALUE]', data[i].id).replace('[TEXT]', data[i].name);
                    }
                    projectSelect.empty().append(options).removeAttr('disabled').trigger('chosen:updated');
                }
            });
        });
        $('#CustomerId').trigger('change');
    });
</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm("GenerateCopyReportExcel", "Report",     FormMethod.Post))
{
//todo - Fix projectids validation

<div id="DlgStockReportSearch" class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3>@Language.KPIReport</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body clearfix">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="CustomerId">@Language.Customer</label>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CustomerId, customerDropdown, new { @class = "form-control chosen", placeholder = Language.Customer })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CustomerId)
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group required">
                        <label for="DateRange">@Language.Date</label>
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.DateRange)
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="ProjectIds">@Language.Projects</label>
                        <div class="input-group button">
                            @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.ProjectIds, projectDropdown, new { @class = "form-control chosen", multiple = ""})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProjectIds)
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default chosen-select-all">Select all</button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="LocationsIds">@Language.Location</label>
                        <div class="input-group button">
                            @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.LocationsIds, locationDropdown, new { @class = "form-control chosen", multiple = "" })
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default chosen-select-all">Select all</button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">@Language.Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    @Language.GenerateReport
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

For some reason, I am able to submit the form even if i leave the listboxfor for projects and locations empty.

Comment: A `[Required]` attribute means that its invalid if its `null` (an empty collection is still valid). You need to implement your own validation attribute if you want to ensure that at least one option is selected. And the code for generating your SelectList's belongs in the controller, not the view.

Comment: And you class names suggest your using plugin for the listboxes (which hide the `<select>` element and replace it with their own html. By default hidden inputs are not validated - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379307/jquery-chosen-dropdown-validation-client-site-doesnt-work/26392882#26392882)

Comment: I just tried without the chosen class, and this works as intended. So it is because of the hidden input then. But the solution from the answer you linked does not work, i might be implementing the jquery posted wrong? i added `$(document).ready(function () {
        $.validator.setDefaults({
            ignore: []
        });
    })` to the script tag

Comment: No, it cannot be in `$(document).ready()` - just add it inside `<script>` tags after the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` scripts

Comment: It does not work, with neither the validator.setdefaults or the form.validate

Comment: Which version of jquery (older versions require a slightly different solution)

Comment: 1.10.2, i have made a hack solution for the time being `$("#kpiForm").submit(function (evt) {
        if ($("#kpiForm #ProjectIds").val() == null) {
            alert("You have to choose atleast 1 project")
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
        else if ($("#kpiForm #LocationsIds").val() == null) {
            alert("You have to choose atleast 1 location")
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
    })`

Comment: There is no reason at all for that hack. Setting the validator options works fine.