# DropDownListFor validation not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Let me explain my issue. I am working on a MVC C# application which uses this calendar for displaying events - https://fullcalendar.io/. The events are court hearings. One of my filters is by "judgePanel". The `judgePanel` property is a string (the id property is for "judgePanel" - there was some problem with that property so finally we left it this way).

This is my model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "* The field is required.")]  
public string id { get; set; }
```

This is my view:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.id, Model.JudgePanels, "choose a judgePanel", new { id = "juror-id", @class = "form-control" })           
</div>
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.id, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

This is my method in EventController:

```
public ActionResult GetHearingsForJudgePanel(string id, int? month = null, int? year = null, int? caseNumber = null, int? caseYear = null)
{
    if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

        int currentMonth;
        int currentYear;
        DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
        EventService service = new EventService();
        IEnumerable<object> data;

        if (id == "")
        {
            id = null;
        }

        string judgePanel = id;

        if (month.HasValue)
            currentMonth = month.Value;
        else
            currentMonth = currentDate.Month;

        if (year.HasValue)
            currentYear = year.Value;
        else
            currentYear = currentDate.Year;

            data = service.GetHearingsForJudgePanel(judgePanel, currentMonth, currentYear, caseNumber, caseYear);

            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Until yesterday the code in the view was:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.id, Model.JudgePanels, "all", new { id = "juror-id", @class = "form-control" })           
</div>
```

Because I had the option "all" that displayed all judgePanels. Now I must remove that option and just want to keep the words: "choose a judgePanel" at the top of the dropdown and I want when someone chooses them, to display a validation message "The field is required" in order to prompt the user to choose a specific judgePanel and in order to make the dropdown required (not to be able to filter without it).

The problem is that when I choose "choose a judgePanel" and filter instead of receiving a validation message, I see again all hearings (for all judgePanels). I debugged the controller method and I saw that `id` (judgePanel) parameter is empty string ("") when I chose "choose a judgePanel" from dropdown.

Please help me receive a normal validation message.

Here is my javascript file that I have put in my view:

```
$("#juror-id").chosen();
```

Comment: Could you show us how you populate the data to JudgePanels?

Comment: The code you have shown will display an error message assuming you have client side validation enabled (but since your making an ajax call, you also need to test `$('form').valid()` first). Show your script and the html of element that your using to trigger the ajax call!

Comment: Stephen Muecke, the code I have shown does not give an error. The problem is that when i choose "choose a judgePanel" from  the dropdown for "judgePanel" (which is a List<SelectListItem>), the "id" (judgePanel) parameter in the controller method is an empty string. This empty become a "null" as shown in the method and when that null value is passed to this method service.GetHearingsForJudgePanel(), this method returns all hearings for all judgePanels. And I want to receive a validation message when "choose a judgePanel" option from the dropdown is choosed, but I do not know how to achieve it.

Comment: Win, here is the code that populates judgePanels:

Comment: public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            CalendarViewModel model = new CalendarViewModel();
            EventService service = new EventService();

            model.JudgePanels = service.GetJudgePanelsForDropDown();

            return View(model);
        }}

Comment: and the service method is:

Comment: public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetJudgePanelsForDropDown()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> selectedJudgePanels = new List<SelectListItem>();

            string constr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DapperConnection"].ToString();

            con = new SqlConnection(constr);

            selectedJudgePanels = con.Query<SelectListItem>(@"SELECT DISTINCT [JudgePanel] As Text, [JudgePanel] As Value FROM [dbo].[JudgePanels]").ToList();

            return selectedJudgePanels;
        }

Comment: @ppetyr, Then clearly you have disabled client side validation, or not included the necessary scripts, or you have other code you have not shown us that is causing the problem. But you have not shown any of the code I asked for (and your code needs to be in the question not in comments) so no one can help

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, I added the javascript file (for the calendar) that I use in my view. To tell you the truth I do not know which is the element that makes the ajax call and I do not know which is its html, that's why I do not display that information

Comment: The only thing that was relevant is one line of code in your script (I have edited everything else out) as you will see from the dupe.

Comment: Damm, I had previous voted to close as off-topic so I cannot dupe-hammer it. Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379307/jquery-chosen-dropdown-validation-client-site-doesnt-work/26392882#26392882) for your issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152707/discussion-between-ppetyr-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript/jquery to make a validation before submit and if the value is empty string trigger a validation or if the value is null on the ActionResult return a value and the use it to show validation you need

Answer (score 0):

try changing your model to this?

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"[^\s]+", ErrorMessage = "*")]
public string id { get; set; }
```

Comment: i tried your suggestion but the result was the same