# Client-side validation on chosen select dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations, jquery-chosen, client-side-validation

I am using asp.net mvc 5. I am working on client-side validation on chosen- dropdown list.

I am facing a problem with required validation. Validation is working fine on button click but when I select the item, validation error message should be removed automatically and when I deselect the item,it should be display validation error message.

This is Model

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Gender is required.")]
   public string Gender { get; set; }
```

This is View

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, new List<SelectListItem>
                   { new SelectListItem{Text="Male", Value="M"},
                     new SelectListItem{Text="Female", Value="F"}}, "Plz Selecct..." , new { @class = "chosen-select"})
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Gender, "", new { @class = "error" })
```

Plaese any input on this it will be appreciable.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Chosen Dropdown validation client site doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379307/jquery-chosen-dropdown-validation-client-site-doesnt-work)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks, but that solution not working for me.My validation works fine in case of submit button but in case of focus chage validation will not working.

Comment: Because the `<select>` you create is hidden - it never gets any focus so it cannot lose focus (look at the html your generating - the `<select>` is styled with `display:none;`)